# Pages/Posts aren't showing up in WordPress backend after move to new server?

Tags: wordpress

Yes, the database has been properly imported in phpmyadmin & yes it's connected to the correct database in wp-config.php ...everything is there in the database in phpmyadmin, but it's not showing up in WP admin? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go in settings and refresh permalinks again?

Later Edit: Actually you should check first if posts were imported in the database and then see if you have the old domain there. Change to new domain manually if not too many posts or do a query to do it...